# How to push updates into form with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have table when i edit any of my rows updates will appear to table but the edit form itself doesn't get update.

## Issue in screenshots

1- My row default values

[image: one]

2- Edit form

[image: two]

3- Input update values

[image: three]

4- Updates appear in table

[image: four]

5- Edit form after update still shows old data **issue part**

[image: five]

> I know that I can use options like `location.reload();` but the purpose of using ajax (to me) is to not reload the page at all.

## code

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var table = $("#data_table2").DataTable();
    $('#data_table2').on('click', '.groupUpdate', function(e){
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        e.preventDefault();
        var ordID = $(this).data('id');

        var name = $(this).closest("form").find("#nameUpdate").val();
        var description = $(this).closest("form").find("#descriptionUpdate").val();

        $.ajax({
            type:'PUT',
            url:'{{url('dashboard/banks')}}/'+ordID,
            data:{
                name:name,
                desc:description
            },
            success:function(data){
                table.cell( row, 0 ).data( data.data.id ); // return new values to table
                table.cell( row, 1 ).data( data.data.name ); // return new values to table
                table.cell( row, 2 ).data( data.data.desc ); // return new values to table

                document.getElementById("updateForm").reset();
                $(".message").append('<div class="alert alert-success fade in">'+data.success+'</div>').hide(4000); // show success message to user
                $('.editModal').modal('hide'); // close the edit modal
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Any idea how to show updates in edit form as well?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset a form that restores the default values. That's why you always see the initial values go back when submitting successfully. Please try just remove the reset operation on the form.